# DateTime formatting doesn't match the culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, locale

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 system which is configured with the default locale settings (no overrides on the format or anything) and it's set to en-US.

When I interrogate the following:
 **System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat**

It is listing the DateSeparator as a *-* (dash) instead of a */* (slash). So DateTime.Now.ToString() would look something like:

*01-30-2015*.

Also, the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() = "en-US"

I'm completely at a loss as to how this is even possible, but more importantly, I would like to know if .NET has some kind of a locale override which is configurable somehow?

The system Region & Language settings are *normal* and have not been changed. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**Here is the code for the diagnostic information. It's being run in asp.net on an aspx page.**

```
Current Date Time: <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
Current Short Date: <%= DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %>
Current Culture: <%= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() %>
Current UI Culture: <%= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentUICulture.ToString() %>

DateTimeFormatInfo invariant = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeForamat;
DateTimeFormatInfo uiThread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat;
DateTimeFormatInfo thread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;

Type type = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.GetType();
foreach( var prop in type.GetProperties()) {
  <%= prop.Name %> 
  <%= prop.GetValue(invariant, null) %> <br/>
  <%= prop.GetValue(uiThread, null) %> <br/>
  <%= prop.GetValue(thread, null) %> <br/>
}
```

**Region & Language Settings**
[image: Region and Language Settings]

**Here is some additional information**
[image: Diagnostic Information about DateTimeFormat]

Comment: Try CurrentUICulture instead of CurrentCulture

Comment: CurrentUICulture is reporting the same thing.

Comment: So presumably you can see this just in a tiny console app? A demo would be really handy, just to make sure we're all thinking of the same things.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've attached an image of the output of some basic DateTime functions.

Comment: Please provide the code for your image example please.  And your Region and Language settings look like [The Default](https://secure.stamps.com/img/rnt_kb_files/RNTimages/regional10.PNG) (Short date is the format M/d/yyyy)?

Comment: I have included some code that is essentially what was used to generate the diagnostic output. And yes, my Region and Language settings do look like the default. Actually, it looks like MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: That's not the default on an en-US machine.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. Despite that, the CultureInfo is still not matching the Region Settings.

Comment: Check the regional settings for the account used by the Application Pool used to run your ASP.NET application.  They may be different from the settings you're looking at in the Regional and Language Settings dialog.

Comment: What happens when you try to get them statically (ie. not from the system settings) with System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")?

Answer (score 2):

Each user has different region profile. Your current account and application may not using same account that why you see the different value.

Go to Region settings windows -> Administrative -> Click on Copy Settings and tick all check box (Welcome screen and system accounts + New user accounts) then click ok. See if it fix your problem. If your app is Web Application you need to create another AppPool to see it affected.